# python How to output floats with dynamic formats

Tags: python, printing

How to output floats with dynamic formats?

for example:

```
a = 23.134

print('%3.5f' %a)
```

output:
23.13400

now I need to use a varible to replace of 3.5,like this:

```
b1 = 3.5

a = 23.134 

print('%b1f' %a)
```

output:
23.13400

how to do it?I would be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructing the formatting string prior to output:

```
a = 23.134
print('%3.5f' %a)

b1 = 3.5
a = 23.134
optfmt = '%' + str(b1) + 'f'
print(optfmt %a)
```

results in

```
23.13400
23.13400
```